# when validating an entry in Tkinter using focusout how do i get the next entry validate method not to trigger when focus is on it

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
   
def validate_name(name):
    if len(name) > 2 and not name.isdigit():
        name_textBox.config(bg='#C4C4C4')      
        return True
    elif any(ch.isdigit() for ch in name):
        name_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')                
        name_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        name_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False  
    elif len(name) == 0:                    
        name_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')
        name_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        name_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False
    elif len(name) <= 2:
        name_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')
        name_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        name_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False
    else:                  
        name_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F') 
        name_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        name_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False                  
                      
def validate_lname(lname):     
    if len(lname) > 2 and not lname.isdigit():
        lname_textBox.config(bg='#FFFFFF')      
        return True
    elif any(ch.isdigit() for ch in lname):
        lname_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')                
        lname_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        lname_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False  
    elif len(lname) == 0:                    
        lname_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')
        lname_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        lname_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False
    elif len(lname) <= 2:
        lname_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')
        lname_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        lname_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False
    else:                  
        lname_textBox.config(bg='#F56B6F')                
        lname_textBox.delete(0, END)  
        lname_textBox.focus_set() 
        return False   

                      

root = Tk()  
name_textBox = Entry(root)
name_textBox.grid(row=0, column=0)
vcmd = root.register(validate_name)
name_textBox.config(validate="focusout", validatecommand=(vcmd,'%P'))
    
    
lname_textBox = Entry(root)
lname_textBox.grid(row=1, column=0)
vcmd1 = root.register(validate_lname)
lname_textBox.config(validate="focusout",validatecommand=(vcmd1,'%P'))
    
root.mainloop()
```

Am new to Python and Tkinter i want to trigger validation on an of a app, where entries in a form are adjacent to each other.
After input into entry if i move my cursor to another entry my app freezes.
How do i fix it
I want each entry to validate and for the App to stop freezing.
I didnt get any error out of it, it simply just froze.
I have no idea why it is happeing.
I have have searched and havent seen any answer about here

Comment: What you say is impossible. Tkinter is single-threaded, meaning one function has to finish before the next one starts. Please provide a complete [mcve] so we can better see what you're seeing.

Comment: Okay i have edited the code and explained alittle more

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: i have formatted the code

Comment: `validatecommand(vcmd1,'%P')` should be `validatecommand=(vcmd1,'%P')`.  After fixing it, cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: that was just a typo,  while formating the code, the app is still freezing when  click the next entry  to focusout during validation

Answer (score 0):

> After input into entry if i move my cursor to another entry my app
> freezes. How do i fix it I want each entry to validate

Both functions are the same, because of duplicated. Actually. you don't need it.
Avoid wildcard from `tkinter import *`
You should use `import tkinter as tk` instead of from tkinter import *

Add two function:

- `testVal()`
- `go_to_next_entry()`
- Then do looping `child for child...`
- Then add `entry.bind('<Return>',...`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

                       
root = tk.Tk()

def testVal(inStr, acttyp):
    if acttyp == '1':
        if not inStr.isdigit():
            return False
    return True

name_textBox = tk.Entry(root, validate="key")
name_textBox['validatecommand'] = (name_textBox.register(testVal),'%P','%d')
name_textBox.grid(row=0, column=0)
#vcmd = root.register(validate_name)
#name_textBox.config(validate="focusout", validatecommand=(vcmd,'%P'))
    
    
lname_textBox = tk.Entry(root, validate="key")
lname_textBox['validatecommand'] = (lname_textBox.register(testVal),'%P','%d')
lname_textBox.grid(row=1, column=0)
#vcmd1 = root.register(validate_lname)
#lname_textBox.config(validate="focusout",validatecommand=(vcmd1,'%P'))

def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list, this_index):
    next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
    print(entry_list[this_index].get())
    entry_list[next_index].focus_set()

  
entries = [child for child in root.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, tk.Entry)]
for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx))

    
root.mainloop()
```